# mysql query to join two tables in order to find elements that don't appear on the right table

Tags: mysql

Need some help to correctly join two tables in MySQL 8+.

The table on the left has customers, the table on the left products. I want to find the customers that have not bought anything yet.

```
create table customers (
  customerID int,
  customerDetails varchar(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
  );

 create table products (
    productID int,
    productDetails varchar(200),
    customerID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (productID),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customers(customerID)
 );

insert into  customers (customerID, customerDetails) VALUES (1,"customer 1");
insert into  customers (customerID, customerDetails) VALUES (2,"customer 2");
insert into  customers (customerID, customerDetails) VALUES (3,"customer 3");

insert into products (productID, productDetails, customerID) VALUES (1,"product 1", 1);
insert into products (productID, productDetails, customerID) VALUES (2,"product 2", 1);
```

So using this schema above the answer should be customer 2 and customer 3. In order to find the answer I used the following statement:

```
select distinct(customers.customerID)  from customers 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON customers.customerID = products.customerID WHERE products.customerID IS NULL
```

The statement seems to work but I would like to ask if my query is on the right direction and if there is a better way (faster/safer) to do it.

Comment: You don't need distinct in this case. Each customer who has not bought anything, will have only 1 row in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The statement seems to work but I would like to ask if my query is on the right direction"* : This is indeed a common way to write such query. However, you can remove the `DISTINCT` clause, there won't be duplicates.

```
select customers.customerID
from customers 
LEFT JOIN products 
ON customers.customerID = products.customerID
WHERE products.customerID IS NULL
```

[image: Ugly graph made by myself to describe this JOIN]

Answer (score 3):

I might use an `EXIST` query here:

```
SELECT 
    c.customerID
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM products p
    WHERE 
        p.customerID = c.customerID
);
```

Comment: faster? or for any other particular reason?

Comment: Performance wise my answer should be about the same as the answer given by @scaisEdge ; I only offer `EXISTS` as another way to write your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct is clause not a function

```
select distinct customers.customerID  
from customers 
LEFT JOIN products ON customers.customerID = products.customerID 
WHERE products.customerID IS NULL
```